# Infinite loop implementation for event based reactive app in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, reactive-programming, reactive, rx-py

I want to write an application that will infinitely generate events and process them in different ways. Precisely, let's say I want to measure temperature each minute and depending on that adjust climate control. I decided to use [RxPY](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY) and idea is to periodically send events from one thread, but schedule their processing on other threads from a pool.

What is the best way to achieve continuous infinite process for that? My current idea is to have a good old `while True:` loop, but for some reason it doesn't seem right for me. Does anybody have any suggestions if this can be implemented differently?

From the main method I do this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    store: Store = Store()
    scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    while True:
        scheduler.enter(5, 1, lambda: store.dispatch(measure_temperature()))
        scheduler.run()
```

and sometime later the following function processes these events like this:

```
epic_scheduler = ThreadPoolScheduler(optimal_thread_count)

def a(action):
    for epic in epics:
        epic(rx.of(action)).subscribe(lambda act: do_stuff(act),
                                      scheduler=epic_scheduler)
```

Something like this for main method seems more appropriate, but how do I make the main thread to not terminate right away?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    store: Store = Store()
    event_loop_scheduler = scheduler.EventLoopScheduler()
    event_loop_scheduler.schedule_periodic(5, lambda arg: store.dispatch(measure_temperature()))
```

Comment: It looks to me as if you want a **generator** that waits for the main program to call on it as needed.

Comment: @Prune i'm not sure if it will be much different, i will still need to have an infinite loop and suspend the thread, won't i?

Comment: That part seems more like an asynchronous timer.

Comment: @Prune so i schedule it on the main thread?

Comment: Check the examples for asynchronous timers.  Yes, you have the timer on one thread, the generator and its calling program on the main one.